# Swift array filter with empty filter value

Tags: arrays, swift

I am filtering an array based on a set filter supplied to the view (this filter varies) but want to modify the function to allow for an empty filter, i.e return the original array un filtered.
I feel like this should be a simple matter but I'm currently a bit lost - have looked at the .isEmpty modifier and a couple of different IF statements but I'm not "getting it"

```
    var categoryFilter:String

var filteredCategoryTasks: [Task] {
    modelData.tasks.filter { task in
        (task.category == categoryFilter)
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65497054/14351818

Comment: This is a Swift question, not SwiftUI -- I've edited the title/tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the original array in the event that the `String` is empty and the filtered array otherwise:

```
var filteredCategoryTasks: [Task] {
    categoryFilter.isEmpty ? modelData.tasks : modelData.tasks.filter { task in
          (task.category == categoryFilter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?